# Set Height of separator between Tab widget and FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm using TabHost in my app and i want to increase the thickness of the strip between tab widget and framelayout.

```
 <TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
 </TabWidget>
 <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"                         android:background="#FF0000">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<TextView android:text="TravelApplication1" android:layout_height="70dip"   android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
<TextView android:text="TravelApplication2" android:layout_height="70dip"       android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
<TextView android:text="TravelApplication3" android:layout_height="70dip"   android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
<TextView android:text="TravelApplication4" android:layout_height="70dip"   android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Kindly suggest me to increse the thickness between tabWidget and FrameLayout.

Regards
Deepak Goel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add margin property to your FrameLayout element will increase space between Tab widget and FrameLayout :

```
 <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
 </TabWidget>
 <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"   android:background="#FF0000">


.......

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: The line in tab widget is default, you have to make a custom tab widget by a layout if you want to custom it.

Comment: Thnx for your response,But it is just shifting my frameLayout down from tabwidget,But my question was how to increase the thickness of a line comes between tabwidget and framelayout

Comment: No problem dude,ya one parallel question with this is that can i change the clor of that line using std tabwidget

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using android:paddingTop/paddingBottom on the tab widget or frame layouts?